# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call - Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I want to automatically assign values by generating cross tab. But I am getting "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" error.

```
For example:
table_1 = pd.crosstab(data_new[target],data_new['col_1'])
table_2 = pd.crosstab(data_new[target],data_new['col_2'])
table_3 = pd.crosstab(data_new[target],data_new['col_3'])
```

This is essential as I don't know for how many columns I need to do crosstab for ( I need not do it for all columns).

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_x':[1,2,3,4],
               'col_y':[5,6,5,6],
               'col_z':[7,7,7,7],
               'col_a':[1,1,1,1],
               'col_b':[4,5,4,5],
               'col_1':[0,0,1,1]})

col_list = [ 'col_x', 'col_y', 'col_z']
target = ['col_1']
for i in range(len(col_list)):
    "table_" + str(i)=pd.crosstab(df[target].iloc[:,0],df[col_list[i]])

File "<ipython-input-108-6d57787a1172>", line 4
"table_" + str(i) = pd.crosstab(df[target].iloc[:,0],df[col_list[i]])
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Got the answer. Thanks !!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You getting syntax error because

```
"table_" + str(i)=pd.crosstab(df[target].iloc[:,0],df[col_list[i]])
```

both the left and the right side of the assignment operator are expressions

I think you may need to use a dictionary to archive this for example

```
dictionnary = {}
for x in range(1,10):
        dictionnary ["table_{}".format(x)]="Hello"
```

if you print dictionary

```
{'table_2': 'Hello', 'table_3': 'Hello','table_1': 'Hello'............
```

for your case

```
col_list = [ 'col_x', 'col_y', 'col_z']
target = ['col_1']
dictionnary = {}
for i in range(len(col_list)):
    dictionnary ["table_{}".format(i)]=pd.crosstab(df[target].iloc[:,0],df[col_list[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
col_list = [ 'col_x', 'col_y', 'col_z']
target = ['col_1']

for i in range(len(col_list)):
    key = 'table_{}'.format(i)
    value = pd.crosstab(df[target].iloc[:,0],df[col_list[i]])
    exec("{} = value".format(key))
```